# Strange behavior in unsung hero query

Tags: support, badges, accepted-answer, data-explorer

I recently notice that I'm close to get the [Unsung Hero Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero) so I run this query
[How Close Am I to Unsung Hero Badge (Including 10 days requirement)?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/121674/how-close-am-i-to-unsung-hero-badge-including-10-days-requirement) with my `userId` 4848308 and I get as result

```
| Accepted Answers| Scored Answers | Unscored Answers| Percentage Unscored |
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 22              |             13 | 9               |       40.9          |
```

The query says that my *Accepted Unscored Answers* is 9. But if I change the query selecting only the *Unscored Answers*

```
select
    sum(case when a.Score = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as [Unscored Answers]
from
    Posts q
  inner join
    Posts a
  on a.Id = q.AcceptedAnswerId
where
      a.CommunityOwnedDate is null
  and a.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
  and q.OwnerUserId != ##UserId##
  and a.postTypeId = 2
  and a.CreationDate < DATEADD(d, -10, GETDATE())
```

The final result is

```
| Unscored Answers|
| ----------------|
|       10        |
```

So I assume there is something wrong with the first query, removing the `count(a.Id) as [Accepted Answers]` the Unscored Answers became 10, like my custom query.

<s>If my query is right, why I still don't get the Unsung Hero Badge?</s>

Question: Is my custom *Unscored Answers* query wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe a timing issue? The original SEDE query returns 10 here.

Comment: I don't know. I get the same problem with those queries. However, note that Unsung only triggers if it's *more* than 10.

Comment: Oh yes!!, I missed that I **must have at least 11** Accepted Unscored Answers. I already have it but have to wait for few days more. Thanks.